# adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory not working for UITextView and UITextField

Tags: ios, dynamic, font-size

I'm switching away from `preferredContentSizeChanged` to use `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory` for my `UILabel`, `UITextView`, and `UITextField` classes. It works for `UILabel`, but not for `UITextView` and `UITextField`. It only works if I call `setNeedsDisplay` inside `preferredContentSizeChanged`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You also need to set the font used by the UITextfield to be scalable:

```
    textField.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    textField.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by OliverD, you will have to set the font to one of the auto-sizing system fonts, along with setting `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory`. That will adjust the text size, but not the overall size of the text field/text view.

To do that, you have to override `traitCollectionDidChange` and adjust the size there.

For example, when setting up your view:

```
    self.intrinsicHeight = textInput.intrinsicContentSize.height
    self.heightConstraint = textInput.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: textField.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    self.heightConstraint?.isActive = true
```

And somewhere else in your view or view controller:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)

    self.heightConstraint.constant = fontMetrics.scaledValue(for: self.intrinsicHeight)
}
```